# spring cloud config high availability with nginx

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, high-availability

I'm using nginx for config-server's proxy. the nginx conf as belows,which proxied two config server:

```
upstream madp.fetch.config {
    server 192.168.28.1:8888 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=2;
    server 192.168.244.128:8888 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=2;}
server{
    listen  80;
    server_name  madp.config.com;
    client_max_body_size 10m;
    location / {
           proxy_pass  http://madp.fetch.config;
           ...     
    }
   }
```

the config server's config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-service
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        monitor:
          git:
           enaled: true
        git:
           uri: git@192.168.244.130:rootGroup/madp.git
```

and the micro service's config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: foo_service
  cloud:
    config:
       uri: http://madp.config.com
```

The question is: the micro-service launched failed with the reason cannot fetch config info from the config server.

Can anyone figure out the mistake?

Comment: Can you provide any more details about the error?

Comment: more info about this question is provided.

Comment: you provided more configuration, but nothing about the actual error.